# java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively

Tags: sqlite, andengine

I'm trying to save my game configuration indatabase, I used a tutorial in this page: [page](http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/guide-how-to-use-sqllite-for-high-scores-t237-10.html).
I make this class called configuracion:

```
public class Configuraciones extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

static final String table_name = "configuraciones";
static final String cod_config = "id";
static final String nom_config = "nombre";
static final String val_config = "valor";

public Configuraciones(Context context) {
    super(context, "bdd_cuarenta", null, 1);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + table_name + "("
            + cod_config + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + nom_config + " TEXT,"
            + val_config + " TEXT" + ");";
    // ESTABLISH NEW DATABASE TABLES IF THEY DON'T ALREADY EXIST IN THE DATABASE
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

    //Ingresa las configuraciones por primera vez
    ingresaTablas(db);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int vieja, int nueva) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table_name);
    onCreate(db);
}

public String consultaConfiguracion(String nombre){
    SQLiteDatabase myDB = getReadableDatabase();
    String[] mySearch = new String[]{nombre};
    Cursor myCursor = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT "+ val_config +" FROM "+ table_name +" WHERE "+ nom_config +"='?'",mySearch);
    myCursor.moveToFirst();
    int index = myCursor.getColumnIndex(val_config);
    String myAnswer = myCursor.getString(index);
    myCursor.close();
    return myAnswer;
}

public int actualizaConfig(String nombre, String nuevaConfig)
{         
        SQLiteDatabase myDB = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(val_config, nuevaConfig);
        int numRowsAffected = myDB.update(table_name, cv, nom_config+"='?'", new String []{String.valueOf(nombre)});
        return numRowsAffected;
}
```

But when i call one of the methods, for example actualizaConfig, I got the error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively

In my game activity I called normaly the object like this:

```
private BoundCamera camera;
private Configuraciones configs;

@Override
public Engine onCreateEngine(EngineOptions pEngineOptions) 
{
    return new LimitedFPSEngine(pEngineOptions, 60);
}

public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions()
{
    camera = new BoundCamera(0, 0, 800, 480);
    configs = new Configuraciones(this);
    EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new FillResolutionPolicy(), this.camera);
    engineOptions.getAudioOptions().setNeedsMusic(true).setNeedsSound(true);
    engineOptions.setWakeLockOptions(WakeLockOptions.SCREEN_ON);
    return engineOptions;
}
```

And in GameScene, i call the method like this:

```
resourcesManager.config.actualizaConfig("diseno_carta", "9");
```

I dont know why is the problem... :(

Comment: The root reason for receiving the error is that you're calling getReadableDatabase() or getWritableDatabase() recursively. I am suggesting you move these calls to a separate method like "Open" and put break points and see how you're calling them. it could be also because of multithreading.

Comment: The complete stack trace would show you where the recursive call is.

Comment: Tanks I solved it deleting some recursive methods in ingresaTablas(db);